# Observable BehaviorSubject Service - Singleton and providers

Tags: angular, service, singleton, behaviorsubject, angular2-providers

I have a simple component `progressBar` in order to display (or not) the progress bar.
And a simple observable service.

Here is the service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable() 
export class ProgressBarService {
  subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
  changes = this.subject
              .asObservable()
              .do(changes => console.log('new state', changes)); 

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }
  show() {
    this.subject.next(true);
  }
  hide() {
    this.subject.next(false);
  }
}
```

Nothing fancy here, just a BehaviorSubject which is set by default with `false`, `hide/show` is used to change the value with `.next()`.

The component looks like this :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { ProgressBarService } from './progressbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-progressbar',
  templateUrl: './progressbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./progressbar.component.scss'],
  providers:[ProgressBarService]
})

export class ProgressbarComponent implements OnInit {

  isDisplay : boolean;

  constructor(private $progressbar : ProgressBarService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.$progressbar
      .changes
      .subscribe((display : boolean) => this.isDisplay = display);
  }

  showProgress(){
    (this.isDisplay)
      ? this.$progressbar.hide()
      : this.$progressbar.show();
  }
}
```

During the init, the component subscribe to the subject in order to get the default value and set it to `isDisplay`.
`showProgress` is only used to try it in my template.

```
<md-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" color="accent" *ngIf="isDisplay"></md-progress-bar>

<button type="submit" md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="showProgress()">Show/hide progressBar</button>
```

And it works just fine when the service is used inside the component.

But, when I try to call this service inside another component, it doesn't work.

Example : My other component called profilesComponent

```
import { ProgressBarService } from ../progressbar/progressbar.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'profiles',
  templateUrl: 'profiles.component.html',
  providers: [ProgressBarService]
})

export class ProfilesComponent implements OnInit {

  toto :boolean = false;

  constructor(private $progressbar : ProgressBarService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  showProgress() {
    if(this.toto) {
      this.$progressbar.hide();
      this.toto = false; 
    } else {
      this.$progressbar.show();
      this.toto = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I think it's because the two component does not share the same instance of the service but i can't find a way to do so. (Maybe providers in `@NgModule`?)

Comment: Yes this could be a reason. declare it in NgModule and remove from both components.

Comment: Holy  **** ! 
You're right, it's the reason. I removed the `ProgressBarService` from the provider's components then I added it to `app.module.js`.
Now they both share the same instance and it works !

Well, thank you sir. I just understood a thing tonight :)

Comment: Great !!! enjoy Angular2 then !

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @micronyks, Here is the solution.

For each component, I add the service in the provider's component. In result, the components create a new instance of the service.

In order to resolve the issue, i removed the service from the providers of each component then provide it to the main module.

```
import { ProgressBarService } from './progressbar/progressbar.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HomeModule,
    MaterialModule.forRoot()
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent, ProgressbarComponent],
  providers: [ProgressBarService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The components now share the same instance and the progress bar is well displayed.